# Finding unit digit of $f(10)$

Tags: calculus, functions, contest-math

> If we define $$f(x)=\left\lfloor \frac {x^{2x^4}}{x^{x^2}+3}\right\rfloor$$ and we have to find unit digit of $f(10)$

I had tried approximation, factorization and substitutions like $x^2=u$ but it proved of no use. Moreover the sequential powers are feeling the hell out of me.  Can someone please provide me with some hints

Comment: This is problem A2 from the 1986 Putnam competition. It is generally appropriate to cite the competition you are taking a problem from.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I had no idea that the question was of Putnam competition and I am really sorry for that and thanks a lot for the reference it will help a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First substitute in $10$ for $x$
$$f(10)=\left\lfloor \frac {10^{2\cdot 10^4}}{10^{10^2}+3}\right\rfloor\\
=\left\lfloor \frac {10^{20000}}{10^{100}+3}\right\rfloor$$
Now ask [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10%5E20000%2F(10%5E100%2B3)%20mod%2010)
[image]
or ask Python
[image]
and the answer is $3$

Added in response to the comment:  You can do long division in base $10^{100}$.  Unfortunately the numerator still has $200$ digits, so it will be a long haul.  The denominator is a simple $13$.  I suspect you are intended to write 
$$f(10)=\left\lfloor \frac {10^{2\cdot 10^4}}{10^{10^2}+3}\right\rfloor\\
=\left\lfloor 10^{19900}\frac {10^{100}}{10^{100}+3}\right\rfloor\\
=\left\lfloor 10^{19900}\frac {1}{1+3\cdot 10^{-100}}\right\rfloor\\
=\left\lfloor 10^{19900}(1-3\cdot 10^{-100}+(3\cdot 10^{-100})^2-(3\cdot 10^{-100})^3+\ldots )\right\rfloor$$
and note that all the terms with exponents less than $199$ get too many zeros from the $10^{19900}$ to matter, then evaluate the term with exponent $199$.  Then note that the term with exponent $200$ doesn't carry and is positive, so you only care about the term with exponent $199$.  We have $-(3^{199})\equiv -7 \equiv 3 \pmod {10}$ so the answer is $3$.

Comment: I don't want an answer which uses some kind of mathematical softwares or programming languages because that would destroy the true essence of the question.

Answer (score 2):

When $x=10$, $\displaystyle \frac {x^{2x^4}}{x^{x^2}+3}=\frac {10^{20000}}{10^{100}+3}$.

Let $y=10^{100}$. $\displaystyle \frac {10^{20000}}{10^{100}+3}=\frac{y^{200}}{y+3}$.

When $y^{200}$ (as a polynomial) is divided by $y+3$, the remainder is $(-3)^{200}=3^{200}$.

So,  $\displaystyle \frac{y^{200}}{y+3}=Q(y)+\frac{3^{200}}{y+3}$ for some polynomial $Q(y)$.

Put $y=0$, $Q(0)=-3^{199}=(-1)(81)^{49}(27)\equiv 3$ (mod $10$).

Note that $\displaystyle \frac{3^{200}}{10^{100}+3}=\frac{9^{100}}{10^{100}+3}<1$.

$$ \frac {10^{20000}}{10^{100}+3}=Q(10^{100})=10^{100}\times \textrm{some positive integer}+3+\frac{9^{100}}{10^{100}+3}$$

The unit digit of $\displaystyle \left\lfloor\frac {10^{20000}}{10^{100}+3}\right\rfloor$ is $3$.